# What version of ZIP is supported by Java (1.6 - or any version for that matter)

Tags: java, zip

There are several versions of the ZIP format (`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29#Version_history`).  It's unclear which version Java supports.  In the source for `ZipOutputStream` it defines a constant related to the "minimum version to read" part of the header, but I'm not 100% certain that's the proper way to reverse engineer an answer to my question.

Can anyone provide better advice here?

Thanks.

Comment: why not use the zip installed on your system `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` where command is string zip -r ...

Comment: @c0mrade Do all windows systems have 'zip' by default? After all, java's supposed to be portable.

Comment: Because i'm zipping directly from a structure in memory -- outsourcing to an app outside the address space makes no sense in my scenario (and no, I don't want to write the data to a temporary file and ZIP from there).  Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: @Nikita Rybak you're right I'm just suggesting alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Info-ZIP Application Note 970311

The compression schemes are listed in the [java.util.zip](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) package summary.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I also saw that, but unfortunately if you click on the link for Info-Zip provided in the package summary, you get issued a login (!) which obviously prevents one from getting at the actual data.  However, since you reminded me of this, I decided to dig deeper and found that you can get the same doc at: http://www.info-zip.org/doc/appnote-19970311-iz.zip.  From there, I got at the actual README-like file, which seems to indicate that the answer is 2.50.  Please let me know if you deduce something different if you pursue this further.  Thanks for the reminder.