# Android unzipping files that where zipped on a Mac

Tags: android, macos, windows-7, osx-lion, zip

I have an application, which downloads a zip and unzips the files on my SDCard.
All works fine, but when my collegue creates the zip file on his Mac (lion), all my files have

**size:-1**

**crc:-1**

**compressedsize:-1**

and I cannot write the files to my sdcard. Both zips have exactly the same content, the only difference is where they where originally zipped. This is the code where I unzip the files:

```
public class UnzipTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    private static final String TAG = UnzipTask.class.getSimpleName();


    private String mDestLocation;
    private ZipListener mListener;
    private Context mCtx;

    private int mCallbackId;

    public UnzipTask(Context context, ZipListener listener, File dir)
    {
        mCtx = context;
        mListener = listener;
        mDestLocation = dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/";

    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        mCallbackId = id;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {


        try {

            String file = arg0[0];
            InputStream is = mCtx.getAssets().open(file);
            unzipFile(is);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Private function that ensures a directory exist
     * @param dir
     */
    private void _dirChecker(String dir) {
        File f = new File(mDestLocation + dir);

        if (!f.isDirectory()) {
            f.mkdirs();
            }
    }

    private void unzipFile(InputStream input) throws Exception {

        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(input);
        ZipEntry ze = null;

        while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {

            Log.v(TAG, "Unzipping " + ze.getName());

            if(mListener != null)
            {
                mListener.onUnzipped(mCallbackId, ze.getName(), ze.g   etSize(), ze.getCrc(), ze.getCompressedSize());
                }

            if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                _dirChecker(ze.getName());
            } else if (ze.getCompressedSize() > 0 && ze.getSize() > 0 && ze.getCrc() != 0.0) {
                // If size=-1 -> writing to disk fails

                String fileOutput = mDestLocation + ze.getName();

                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(fileOutput);
                int read = 0;

                byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) ze.getSize()];

                while ((read = zin.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                    fout.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }

                zin.closeEntry();
                fout.close();
                } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "Skipping entry" + ze.getName());
            } 
            }
        }

        zin.close();
    }

}
```

**A couple of notes**

**1)** I can unzip both files on my windows 7 pc

**2)** My collegue can unzip both files on his Mac

**3)** The only problem is, on Android I cannot unzip the zip file the MAC creates...

**QUESTION:**

Does anyone know why the zip file that was zipped on a Mac has these invalid sizes? Is my Unzipping process (on Android) missing some code?

You can download the zips here if you want, as well as a very small apk to show the output:

EDIT: updated the links

[Zip file (zipped on a Mac)](http://www.haarmodemanowi.nl/stackoverflow/test_mac.zip)

[Zip file (zippen on Win7)](http://www.haarmodemanowi.nl/stackoverflow/test_win.zip)

[Demo.apk](http://www.haarmodemanowi.nl/stackoverflow/Stackoverflow.apk)

Comment: Your web host has suspended download of the sample zip files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue relates to version.  Let me start with some output from my Mac (10.8):

```
~ $ zipinfo -m test_mac.zip 
Archive: test_mac.zip   1694 bytes   8 files
drwxr-xr-x  2.1 unx        0 bx  0% stor 10-Aug-12 01:11 test_win/
-rwxr-xr-x  2.1 unx       46 bX 20% defN 10-Aug-12 01:11 test_win/index.html
drwxrwxr-x  2.1 unx        0 bx  0% stor 10-Aug-12 01:12 __MACOSX/
drwxrwxr-x  2.1 unx        0 bx  0% stor 10-Aug-12 01:12 __MACOSX/test_win/
-rw-r--r--  2.1 unx      211 bX 37% defN 10-Aug-12 01:11 __MACOSX/test_win/._index.html
-rwxr-xr-x  2.1 unx        9 bX-21% defN 10-Aug-12 01:10 test_win/version.txt
-rw-r--r--  2.1 unx      211 bX 37% defN 10-Aug-12 01:10 __MACOSX/test_win/._version.txt
-rw-r--r--  2.1 unx      211 bX 37% defN 10-Aug-12 01:11 __MACOSX/._test_win
8 files, 688 bytes uncompressed, 450 bytes compressed:  34.6%
~ $ zipinfo -m test_win.zip 
Archive: test_win.zip   1678 bytes   8 files
drwx---     3.1 fat        0 bx  0% stor 10-Aug-12 09:11 test_win/
-rw-a--     3.1 fat       46 bx 20% defN 10-Aug-12 09:11 test_win/index.html
-rw-a--     3.1 fat        9 bx-21% defN 10-Aug-12 09:10 test_win/version.txt
drwx---     3.1 fat        0 bx  0% stor 10-Aug-12 09:12 __MACOSX/
-rw-a--     3.1 fat      211 bx 37% defN 10-Aug-12 09:11 __MACOSX/._test_win
drwx---     3.1 fat        0 bx  0% stor 10-Aug-12 09:12 __MACOSX/test_win/
-rw-a--     3.1 fat      211 bx 37% defN 10-Aug-12 09:11 __MACOSX/test_win/._index.html
-rw-a--     3.1 fat      211 bx 37% defN 10-Aug-12 09:10 __MACOSX/test_win/._version.txt
8 files, 688 bytes uncompressed, 450 bytes compressed:  34.6%
```

Have a look at the second field (2.1 in the mac file and 3.1 in the win file).  This is the ZIP archive format version that the file was compressed against.  The `java.util.zip` implementation only supports version 2.50 and higher of the ZIP file format (See this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348157/what-version-of-zip-is-supported-by-java-1-6-or-any-version-for-that-matter)).

The Mac's **Compress ...** menu option uses a version below what the Java implementation supports (2.1 is still used in 10.8 as well).

Tell your colleague to use the command line tool instead (e.g. `zip -r myfile.zip directory_to_compress/`) and you should get an output that the Android application can inflate.

Comment: @Devunwired, I 'm trying to unzip file,but I can still unzip 1.0 fat in Android,Problem is I can't 2.0 fat for Android.Is there any code or library to unzip for all zip file types in Android

Answer (score 0):

These files are very different... Hard to look for important differences.[image]

Comment: true, the Mac automatically adds the __MACOSX directory, or something similar. I like the idea of analysing the zip files with a hexeditor. For now, i know there is a difference, but i want to know how to be able to extract mac-zipped-file on my Android device. For the size=-1 is causing the program to freeze

Comment: I have updated the win_zip file. It should now be an exact copy, e.g. including the __MACOSX directory.